# Shared sub-directory between multiple users

Tags: permissions, users

I have two users with home directories:

```
/home/user1/
/home/user2/
```

I would like to share a folder between the two users:

```
/home/user1/some/path/to/folder
```

but would only like user2 to have access to /home/user1/some/path/to/folder and not any of the parent directories.  I tried to chmod 777 /home/user1/some/path/to/folder, but that didn't work.

Comment: You may try to use `sshfs` to create a "virtual" directory accessible by both users.

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/File_permissions_and_attributes

Answer (score 0):

The `/home` directory has the execute permission set for everyone so that users can move into their homes inside but each user's home only has permissions for the user (unless configured otherwise for some reason).

The only way to get **exactly** what you want is by creating a group containing `user2` and giving it execute permissions for home of `user1` and the directories above the one that you want to share to make them traversable by `user2` and then set the full permissions on the full directory. I would not recommend doing this as `user2` would be able to ls specific files and subdirectories inside of the home of `user1` which is a bad idea. You don't want to give another user permissions to someone else's home.

A better way to accomplish this would be to either make a directory in `/` and create a group containing the users and give them permissions to it or to create an nfs export with permissions for the two users only and mount it on the machine. Once again, do not give another user access to someone else's home.